# Why is a disconnected bone still following its former parent?

Tags: bones

I've disconnected 2 bones, with Alt P > Disconnect. They are definitely disconnected - they move independently in Edit Mode and under the Properties > Bone tab > Relations no parent is shown for them. But then when I move their former parents in Pose Mode, they follow along as though there was a Keep Offset parenting on them. That shouldn't happen, right? I've tried it several times. There's no constraint on the disconnected bone, no drivers.

[image]

Comment: apparently there is no tag for anything like 'parent' or 'child'. I don't know what gets used instead.

Comment: I tried creating a new bone and doing the same thing. No dice. In fact, i can see that right after unparenting it, when i select it and try to move it, the former parent immediately reappears in the Bone > Relations Parent field.

Comment: Does anybody show up in the objects parent options?

Comment: I added a snapshot. Nope.

Comment: Was  it extruded from that bone? You might need to press `P` *> Separate by Selection*

Comment: Well that's just annoying... it is now behaving normally, making me sound a little crazy. I checked several times before posting, and can't imagine what i could have done slightly wrong and not noticed. I guess i might need to delete the question... But it DID re-add the parenting right before my eyes after i'd cleared that field in the test bone i created.

Comment: do you have a saved blend to check?

Comment: @Bithur With the odd behavior you mean? No, i didn't want to save a wonky file. But my new issue is that i tried to put a IK constraint on the former parent as the next step, and when i did, it created an empty from nowhere and made it the target. And i videoed that. I could put it on YouTube and link...

Comment: are you human or some kind of bone destroying monster? :) What you say is really weird! Some problem with shortcuts maybe? (bone constraints are...complex)

Comment: empty added when no target (bone) selected. Adding IK or some targeted constraint (IK, track,...) adds an empty as target if none selected. It's not an old behavior...

Comment: @Bithur eeep. My credibility is waning fast...

Comment: I just discovered it too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to really delete the parenting. In edit mode select your bone, in bone's options tab it's parent should appear, click X.

[image]

But the real problem was...

In pose mode, adding a constraint that needs a target (IK, track,...) with hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should be done selecting it (the target) first, then the bone to constraint. If you don't select a target, an empty is added and becomes the target. This won't happen using the constraint menu.

Comment: five bucks and +1 for doing this *as* I commented...

Comment: did that... see added graphic

Comment: no parent, no constraint, no driver, no keyframe???

Comment: In fairness, the parenting thing all happened before i tried to add the constraint. I was trying to push on once it behaved the way i expected.

Comment: i'd really like to see the not saved blend. And a detailed undo list to see what happened.

Comment: @Vince Scalia forget the bucks and throw a beer! (for children : don't throw beers at home)

Comment: @Noted for future reference. That in itself is a useful lesson.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21056/discussion-between-briligg-and-bithur).